# find the value of $m$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The plane $m_1(x − 1) + m_2(y − 2) + m_3(z − 3) = 0$ is tangent to the
surface $x^3 + y^3 -z^3  + 3xyz = 0$ at the point $(1, 2, 3)$. What are the values of
$m_i$,   $1 ≤ i ≤ 3$ such that   $\sum_{i=1}^3 m_i^2 = 1$?

i was trying this question many time but i could not able to solve this question.
i was taking three tangent which is passes through the  sphere.i was also locating this coordinates at point $(1,2,3)$. But  i don't how from where i have to start.i could not able to find the tangent to the sphere. i was trying to solved many times but didn't get it.
if anybody help me i would be very thankful to him.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $\vec{N_{\text{plane}}} = t\vec{N_{\text{surface}}} \implies (m_1,m_2,m_3) = t(3x^2+3yz, 3y^2+3xz, -3z^2+3xy)|_{(1,2,3)}= t(21,21,-21)= (21t,21t,-21t)\implies m_1 = m_2 = -m_3\implies 3m_1^2 = 1\implies m_1 = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}= m_2 = \mp \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=m_3$

Comment: i m not getting the line t( 3x^2 +3yz ,3y^2 + 3 xz...,,)/ 1,2,3@ deap sea